# How to make a Twitter-like Header in NextJS and TailwindCSS?

Tags: twitter, next.js, header, navbar, tailwind-css

I am making a website with a header like Twitter. I've seen that Twitter in mobile, has it's navigation panel in bottom and user panel in top and in large screen device, everything is in left. How do I do that with NextJs and Tailwind CSS ?.

This is how navbar like in large screen ==>>
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ6QZ.jpg

And this is how navbar looks like in mobile ==>>
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmLrK.jpg

Please help me !

Comment: If your new to stackoverflow please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. You can not just ask for such a big feature to be done for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **hidden** class and create two elements.

- one for larger screens
- one for smaller screens

  ```
   <div class="hidden sm:grid">
  ```

this hides the div element below small screens and shows above small screens.

Here is a sample codepen if you want to check it out,
[Twitter Header Sample](https://codepen.io/ishankadsenevirathne/pen/mdxoXOz)

Answer (score 0):

you should design web app desktop first.
it means that please code a component like twitter desktop menu on left.
then in _app.js, import that. fix it in left with

```
className="sticky top-20 h-[100vh]"
```

and in the mobile, please get that

```
className="fixed -left-[100%]"
```

and with click of a button, it should be

```
className="fixed left-0"
```

.

it is responsive and you can see responsive page in tailwind website and react or nextjs responsive nav bar on youtube.
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design

my website is mernfa.ir . i haven't menu like this but maybe help you it's code. this is with next.js and tailwind.css